# How to create a Ruby on Rails 3 gem with a generator to copy file to /assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I create a gem generator, it seems does not work at all. Is there any tutorial you would recommend?

Comment: here is an example: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/lib/generators/gmaps4rails/install_generator.rb

Answer (score 1):

My colleague [did something similar](https://github.com/samknight/gollum_editor/blob/master/lib/generators/gollum_editor/install_generator.rb).

Take a look through that gem and it should be easy enough to replicate.

Instead of `directory` you might need `template`:

```
template('app/assets/stylesheets/gemstyles.css', 'app/assets/stylesheets/gemstyles.css')
```